# mysql query: how to join and count duplicates and order by that count

Tags: php, mysql, join, count, duplicates

I got 2 tables. The 'table_a' has more columns that need to be joined to one result:

```
'table_a' (time, col_1, col_2,....col_50) //'col_[1-50]' columns contains '$id'

example col_1 values: (1000, 1000, 1000, 2000, 2000, 2000)
example col_2 values: (2000, 2000, 1000, 2000, 3000, 3000) //etc

'table_b' ($id, name) //contains 'name' acording to '$id' from 'table_a'

example id,name values: (1000, John), (2000, Peter), (3000, Annie) //etc
```

I need some complex query like I tried write in words for you (I know, funny way):

```
SELECT and JOIN or UNION col_[1-50] from table_a AS some 'result row'
AND count(*) duplicates/occurrences AS 'count', (DISTINCT after that)
(then GET 'name' FROM 'table_b' according to '$id') 
and ORDER BY that 'count'
```

final query result should be like:

```
echo $query['count']." - ".$query['name']." - ".$query['id']."<br>";

6 - Peter - 2000
4 - John - 1000
2 - Annie - 3000
```

Thank you guys, I'm lost....

Comment: In the comment line on the table_b "declaration" in the first code section it says "contains 'name' acording to '$id' from 'table_a'". What exactly does this mean? I don't see an id field in table_a anywhere.

Comment: hi, it means that values of col_1 - col_50 are literally id's like you can see when you compare example values of both tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
  SELECT tb.name, 
         SUM(
           (tb.id = ta.col_1),
           (tb.id = ta.col_2),
           ...
           (tb.id = ta.col_50)
         ) count, 
         tb.id
    FROM table_a ta
    JOIN table_b tb
  /*  ON tb.id IN (
           ta.col_1,
           ta.col_2,
           ... 
           ta.col_50
         ) /* Not strictly necessary, but may help performance */
GROUP BY tb.id, tb.name
```

I would suggest your data structure could be improved. Personally I would store `table_a` with two columns, `property_id` and `person_id`, and separate each current row into 50 rows. It'll make queries like this much simpler.

Comment: thank you, I will try it. Actually those tables are more complex and one is related to web orders and second is table with shop products, I've just made it simple according data I need to grab from it to be viewed

Comment: No problem. Happy to help! I still think your data structure could be improved :)